# Real time continuous animation with SceneKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, scenekit

I want to be able to apply animations in real time to an SCNNode.
Basically, I have a node and I want to continuously input angles to it and have it animate in near real time. I've tried runActions:

```
 var action1:SCNAction = SCNAction.rotateByX(CGFloat(45 / 180.0 * M_PI), y: 0.0, z: 0.0, duration: 0.5);
```

but the problem with actions is that if I have a stream of actions on the same node, it will only animate the latest action, you can't have it animate multiple actions. Then I ran across sequences, but sequences are a static array and so they cannot be populated dynamically in real time.

So my question is does anyone know of a way to animate an scnnode with streaming data. It doesn't have to be in real time, but that would be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried simply setting the rotation? If you have enough data per frame it should be as smooth as it can be. That's what I use for VR.

Else, you can use the `lerp()` function, very popular with Unity to do this. I do not think this is built in Scenekit but we can use [GLKVector4Lerp](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKVector4/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/GLKVector4Lerp). Here's an Objective-C sample:

```
- (void)renderer:(id <SCNSceneRenderer>)aRenderer updateAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)time
{
    yourNode.rotation = GLKVector4Lerp(yourNode.rotation, newRotation, (float)time);      
}
```

That way you can continuously send data and the node will smoothly follow, without jumping.

Comment: Hey @Moustach, so finally got around to implementing this, how excatly do I implement it? This is a delegate function right? so ive put it in my class file but how do I call it? what should i send it?

Comment: Easy: just subclass you SCNView or any object so that it supports the `<SCNSceneRendererDelegate>` protocol. Then implement the function I gave you before (you'll need some type conversion). It will be called by the renderer as it is part of the delegate. Here is the related documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRendererDelegate_Protocol/

Comment: Right but is there a way to make sure that method gets fired. Right now it gets fired when the scene gets created and I can't quite figure out how to get it to run again other then by moving my model with the mouse which I'd like to avoid

Comment: Try setting the `playing` property of your scene to `YES`. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: I don't think the scene has a playing property does it?

Comment: Ok so it kind of is working but not really, its really jumpy and doesn't animate smoothly at all. Also I don't think its animating to the right angles. Can you think of another way to accomplish this?

Comment: I ended up using scnaction instead, but I'll accept your answer for giving me the idea to use a delegate.

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer. I'm not sure what could go wrong, is the framerate still high enough? I guess if the actions are working it's good but this could give you a little bit more control.